# Group theory libraries in C?

Tags: group-theory, math-software

Are there any (ideally well-known/optimized) C libraries that implement basic group theory? I'm familiar with GAP but from what I can tell it can't be used as a C library and included in other C projects.

Comment: The GAP kernel is written in C, and there is a way to allow 3rd party code to link GAP as a library, called `libgap` (search for `libgap` in https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/master/CHANGES.md). The open GAP development mailing list (link at front page of https://www.gap-system.org/) is the best way to ask questions about it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. That didn't turn up in my searches and the only comments I could find on the matter were negative. I will look into that and ask on the mailing list. @alexanderkonovalov